# Cryptic Clojure error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Symbol

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to make leiningen work. I am using Windows 7. When I run in the command window

```
C:\lein new app my-app
```

I get the following error. Does anyone know what this means and where the error is occuring?

There is an explanation of the error message [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-5) but I did not understand if there is a fix or what causes the error.

```
C:\Users\a\work>lein new app my-app
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Symbol
        at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:857)
        at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:807)
        at leiningen.core.project$dep_key.invoke(project.clj:175)
        at leiningen.core.project$reduce_dep_step.invoke(project.clj:183)
        at clojure.lang.ArrayChunk.reduce(ArrayChunk.java:58)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6041.invoke(protocols.clj:98)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6005$G__6000__6014.invoke(protocols.clj:19
)
        at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:31)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6024.invoke(protocols.clj:60)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5979$G__5974__5992.invoke(protocols.clj:13
)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6177)
        at leiningen.core.project$meta_merge.invoke(project.clj:391)
        at clojure.core$merge_with$merge_entry__4279.invoke(core.clj:2698)
        at clojure.core$reduce1.invoke(core.clj:896)
        at clojure.core$merge_with$merge2__4281.invoke(core.clj:2701)
        at clojure.core$reduce1.invoke(core.clj:896)
        at clojure.core$reduce1.invoke(core.clj:887)
        at clojure.core$merge_with.doInvoke(core.clj:2702)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439)
        at leiningen.core.project$meta_merge.invoke(project.clj:395)
        at leiningen.core.project$apply_profiles$fn__1009.invoke(project.clj:417
)
        at clojure.lang.ArrayChunk.reduce(ArrayChunk.java:58)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6041.invoke(protocols.clj:98)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6005$G__6000__6014.invoke(protocols.clj:19
)
        at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:31)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6026.invoke(protocols.clj:54)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5979$G__5974__5992.invoke(protocols.clj:13
)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6177)
        at leiningen.core.project$apply_profiles.invoke(project.clj:415)
        at leiningen.core.project$init_profiles.doInvoke(project.clj:603)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__1332.invoke(main.clj:257)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:252)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:423)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
        at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:335)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:431)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
C:\Users\a\work
```

Comment: This looks like a lein bug. The error means that it is trying to treat a symbol as a list (likely in a destructuring context), it seems like it may be somewhere in evaluating the project.clj that it just generated for the app.

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling lein? Which version are you using and where did you download it?

Comment: Find a lein version that works better on your OS, or use an OS better supported by lein, I guess. I get the impression that most clojure developers use OSX or Linux, so the tools tend to be more stable on those platforms.

Comment: @rörd and @noisesmith Thanks. I reinstalled lein with `lein.bat` instead of Windows installer and it is all working now. Can one of you please add this as an answer so that I can select it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here's my comment transferred into an answer. I suggested reinstalling Leiningen because apparently a broken Leiningen installation was the source of the problem.

As a little background explanation, I'm using Leiningen on both Linux and Windows, and I've made the experience myself that the primary method for installing Leiningen recommended on [its homepage](http://leiningen.org/), the `lein` resp. `lein.bat` script, just works, whereas the alternative 
installation methods (Linux package managers, Windows installer) often produce broken installations.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's highly unlikely that this is essentially a leiningen error, since I can reproduce it without leiningen being involved in any way:

user=> (let [[foo bar] :froboz] (list foo bar))

UnsupportedOperationException nth not supported on this type: Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:857)